# How to fix blocked view transition to augmented reality view

Tags: swift, persistence, augmented-reality, arkit

I am using placenote sdk to provide stored persistent maps for my application but when I click the button to transition to the augmented reality map view, it just shows a blank screen

```swift
    @IBAction func button1(_ sender: Any) {
        if (!placenoteSessionRunning)
        {
            placenoteSessionRunning = true
            LibPlacenote.instance.loadMap(mapId: "0170582d-4425-4194-a71e-1c8b8eebe90f",
                                          downloadProgressCb: {(completed: Bool, faulted: Bool, percentage: Float) -> Void in
                                            if (completed) {
                                                LibPlacenote.instance.startSession()
                                            }
            })
        }
    }
```

It should load the persistent map in a new view.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up the `PNDelegate`? If so, check the `onStatusChange` method to see if the `currStatus` variable is `running`

Comment: Yes! That is set up